# How use IAP for Windows Store? (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, windows-store

We are trying to add In App Purchase to our game for Microsoft Windows Store.
We installed latest unity purchasing package and also did unity purchase configurations for our products.
At store website we created the game and its add-ons.
We also used this simple code from Jack's Video tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gie0A84tPgg

Is there any special Windows Store related code or library we need to add?

Fake store is also working fine in unity editor. but after uploading the Game and testing it, Purchasing cannot be done and IAP buttons are not working.

```
public class IAPScript : MonoBehaviour
{
   private string OneHundredCoins = "100coins";
   private string FiveHundredCoins = "500coins";
   private string TwoThousandCoins = "2000coins";
}

public void PurchaseCompleted(Product product)
{
    if (product.definition.id == OneHundredCoins)
        IAP.coinAmount += 100;  
    
    if (product.definition.id == FiveHundredCoins)
        IAP.coinAmount += 500;

    if (product.definition.id == TwoThousandCoins)
        IAP.coinAmount += 2000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the function inside the class and make sure you call the function from the button.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).